# Transition from one screen to another through ListView

Tags: android

In android project/application,I want to display screen2 containing listview when the list item of screen1 gets clicked.I  have tried a lot but after clicking on screen1, screen2 is not desplaying.And can u tell me where should i write the code for onClick event of listview of screen1 and displaying code of listview of screen2....that is should i create different class other than the class created while creating new project ?...Please help me by giving complete code for both the listviews...i have tried a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough, Start a new activity when the user clicks on a listview item.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);

     }

});
```

Comment: plz can u tell me,where to write this code (in onCreate method or outside separately)?..plz help

Comment: probably in your onCreate method.

Answer (score 1):

call startactivity or startactivityForResult.

Android developer site has more information regarding this

Answer (score 1):

```
    In layout xml:
<anyView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/item" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/openItem"  android:onClick="onItemClick"></anyView>

    Then in Activity.java
public void onItemClick(View v){
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1000);
startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: can I write the code of onClick event of a button and listview  in the same class/java file?

Answer (score 0):

yeah with the method setOnItemClickListener you can set a simple listener that change the view when you make click on an item list, but the problem is when you have a costum item list (and xml from where you make you UI for each list row) with view objects that can take the focus (for instance imageview, button, etc) if this is your case, so you have to set the LISTENER to the root layout of each list row.

In code:

```
//your root layout of each row
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detailed_view_row,
                        null);
//set the listener to your root layout
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
                }
                });
```